# Cygwin "using: command not found" for C++ program

Tags: c++, cygwin, using

Hoping to free myself from Eclipse and not wanting to keep using the online cpp.sh, I wrote a small program in Cygwin in nano and tried to run it. The code is included for clarity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int i;
  string mystr;

  cout << "Enter number: ";
  cin >> i;
  cout << "You entered: " << i;
  cout << " and its double: << i*2 << ".\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cout << "Name: ";
  getline(cin, mystr);
  cout << "Hello " << mystr << ".\n";
  cout << "Team? ";
  getline(cin, mystr);
  cout << "Go " << mystr << "! \n";
  return 0;
}
```

Trying to run it returns a series of errors, as seen in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xayw.png). Right now, I'm trying to understand why "using" is not recognized. Checking Google found many similar complaints, but never about the command "using," probably because "using" is a common enough word to be *using* in a different context.

Comment: One problem is a missing `"` after `double:`. Start by fixing that.

Comment: Your first failure is easily explained: source code is NOT executable.  Your shell is trying to interpret it as shell commands, without success.  Second failure is due to mismatched quotes in your source code.  In the future, put the compile command and resulting error messages as TEXT in your question, not just a screen capture.

Comment: You're trying to execute a source file, you need to compile your code info a proper executable first (btw a double-quote is missing line 14).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run source code directly. You must compile it first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a lot of g++ compile errors are because you have

```
cout << " and its double: << i*2 << ".\n";
```

when you probably meant

```
cout << " and its double: " << i*2 << ".\n";
```

with one more quotation mark

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you insert the " into line 14 it will compile and run, but the last portion will not complete.

I would also create another string near mystr, and use it for `getline()`. Reusing mystr faults when I compile it.
    `int main()
    {
    int i;
    string mystr;
    string team;`

```
`getline(cin, team);
cout << "Go " << team << "! \n";`
```

After changing and compiling, I get:
    `Enter number: 3
    You entered: 3 and its double: 6.
    Name: Aaron
    Hello Aaron.
    Team? Meow
    Go Meow!`